# Download all attachments from an IMAP folder

Tags: gratis, imap, email-attachments

I have an IMAP folder somewhere containing thousands of attached files.

How to download all of these attachments?

- A program focused on this task is preferred, not a human-facing email reading/composing program that happens to also download attachments if you click here and there
- Command-line tool preferred
- Free, ideally open source

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a [python](http://python.org) script, the following example would download and print the text from all messages, *(courtesy of the python [documents](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html#imap4-example))*.

```
import getpass, imaplib

M = imaplib.IMAP4()
M.login(getpass.getuser(), getpass.getpass())
M.select()
typ, data = M.search(None, 'ALL')
for num in data[0].split():
    typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    print 'Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, data[0][3])
M.close()
M.logout()
```

But in your case you need to specify the attachments as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225763/downloading-multiple-attachments-using-imaplib) SO answer, (second one looks to fill your needs).

- Free
- Command Line
- Customisable
- Open Source
- Just about any platform from Raspberry Pi to a super computer cluster *even OS-X or Windows*

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla Thunderbird has an [attachment extractor](/addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/attachmentextractor/) addon which can be instructed to extract attachments from an entire IMAP folder at once. It also can remove attachments from e-mails after extraction to save space (which is the main reason I extract attachments).